# Get childrens DOM element height 'before' it´s mounted in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, dom

In a Vuejs app, I have component A which manages instances of component B. When A mounts, it iterates over a list, from which it creates B components. While it iterates, A creates a new instance of B, and then it needs to know the height of a specific div element inside B´s template, before B is really mounted into the DOM (yea I know). A then decides what to do with the B instance based on the height.

I tried this approach where the idea is to mount the B instance to the DOM, to afterward remove it, if it is to tall:

A:

```
for(let i = 0; i < bData.length; i++) {
    const bInstance = new B();
    this.bInstances.push(bInstance);
    this.$nextTick(() => {
        const height = bInstance.getHeight();
        if(height < 100) {
            //...
        } else {
            //...
        }
    });
}
```

B:

```
getHeight() {
    const divContent = this.$refs.divContent;
    return divContent.clientHeight;     
}
```

I have two problems here; First of all, I need to wait for the first B instance to be mounted to know the height, before A continues with the next B item. Kind of like an await function. But the loop is of course not waiting for the netTick to be done.
Secondly, when calling B´s getHeight function, the $refs object is empty? If I set a timeout in the mounted function in B, the $refs are available. How come?

I guess I am not approaching the problem correctly. Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you want to remove it if it is too tall?

Anyway if you want to do that, you could add a boolean to the props of B component, then bind it to a prop in A component upon creation of B component inside A component

Also you can loop through the data that you want in B component directly in a div with the vueJs v-for attribute when mounting it in the A component, it makes it easier to work with the data and attributes

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by creating B instances in a temporary list, and then mount them in a temporary div in the DOM. Then A looped through the B´s via refs and took note of there height. From there I could discard the temporary div, and A can now continue it´s process knowing the height of each B element.